# AcquireTokenAsync is not providing any result it is taking long time in Bot V4

Tags: .net, azure, botframework, azure-keyvault

I am working on bot framework v4 i was getting retry couldn't send for my first question in bot v4

when i dubugged my code i realized that if bot is idle for some time not able to get the token from AcquireTokenAsync method.

how my bot will work is first my bot will send a welcome message then user asks questions and the bot will give the reply here my problem is when user sends a first message the bot is giving could not send retry if i click retry only the bot is giving the response

this is my DialogBot.cs code

```
    protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var welcomeUserStateAccessor = _conversationState.CreateProperty<WelcomeUserState>(nameof(WelcomeUserState));
            var didBotWelcomeUser = await welcomeUserStateAccessor.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new WelcomeUserState());
            if (didBotWelcomeUser.DidBotWelcomeUser == false)
            {
                didBotWelcomeUser.DidBotWelcomeUser = true;
            }

                await _dialog.Run(turnContext, _conversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(nameof(DialogState)), cancellationToken);
        }

        public override async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            
            await base.OnTurnAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);

            // Save any state changes that might have occured during the turn.
            await _conversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
        }
       
        protected override async Task OnMembersAddedAsync(IList<ChannelAccount> membersAdded, ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            foreach (var member in membersAdded)
            {

                if (member.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id)
                {
                   // var welcomeCard = CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment();
                   // var response = CreateResponse(turnContext.Activity, welcomeCard);
                    //await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(response, cancellationToken);
                    IConversationUpdateActivity iConversationUpdated = turnContext.Activity as IConversationUpdateActivity;
                    MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(turnContext.Activity.ServiceUrl);
                    string appId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MicrosoftAppId"];
                    string appPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MicrosoftAppPassword"];
                    var account = new MicrosoftAppCredentials(appId, appPassword);
                    var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(turnContext.Activity.ServiceUrl), account);

                    //ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new System.Uri(turnContext.Activity.ServiceUrl));

                    var userName = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(turnContext.Activity.From.Name) ? turnContext.Activity.From.Name.Split('.')[0] : "User";

                    userName = CapitalizeFirstLetter(userName);
                    var replyMessage = string.Format("Hello {0} ! I can assist you with RFP questions related to the topics listed in the What to Ask section. To start, please type in your question.", userName);
                    var reply = ((Activity)iConversationUpdated).CreateReply(replyMessage);
                    await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
                }
            }
        }


This is the code for Global.asax file

protected void Application_Start()
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(BotConfig.Register);
        }

        public static class BotConfig
        {
            public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
            {
                var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
                builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
                //builder.RegisterType<MessagesController>().InstancePerRequest();
                // The ConfigurationCredentialProvider will retrieve the MicrosoftAppId and
                // MicrosoftAppPassword from Web.config
                builder.RegisterType<ConfigurationCredentialProvider>().As<ICredentialProvider>().SingleInstance();

                // Create the Bot Framework Adapter with error handling enabled.
                builder.RegisterType<AdapterWithErrorHandler>().As<IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter>().SingleInstance();

                // The Memory Storage used here is for local bot debugging only. When the bot
                // is restarted, everything stored in memory will be gone.
               // IStorage dataStore = new MemoryStorage();


               // AzureBlobStorage _myStorage = new AzureBlobStorage("<your-blob-storage-account-string>", "<your-blob-storage-container-name>");

                string botdialogstorage = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BotDialogStorageContainer"];
                string storageConnectionString = KeyVaultManager.GetKeyVaultSecret(CDPOSConfigurationManager.GetAppSetting("StorageConnectionStringSecret"));
                CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);
                CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
                CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(botdialogstorage);
                AzureBlobStorage _myStorage = new AzureBlobStorage(storageConnectionString, container.Name);
                // Create Conversation State object.
                // The Conversation State object is where we persist anything at the conversation-scope.
                var conversationState = new ConversationState(_myStorage);
                builder.RegisterInstance(conversationState).As<ConversationState>().SingleInstance();

                // Register the main dialog, which is injected into the DialogBot class
                builder.RegisterType<RootDialog>().SingleInstance();

                // Register the DialogBot with RootDialog as the IBot interface
                builder.RegisterType<DialogBot<RootDialog>>().As<IBot>();

                var container1 = builder.Build();
                var resolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container1);
                config.DependencyResolver = resolver;
            }
        }
In RootDialog.cs file i am calling keyvault secret but some times i am able to get key and sometimes not if the bot is idle or when i am sending the first question to bot the bot is not responding when i debug the code the issue is with the below kevaultsecret method.

    string storageConnectionString = KeyVaultManager.GetKeyVaultSecret(CDPOSConfigurationManager.GetAppSetting("StorageConnectionStringSecret"));
```

please let me know what i am doing wrong

Comment: are you following any specific sample?

Comment: no samples followed